# Is it possible to substring an environment variable in a windows 7 shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, shortcuts, environment-variables, file-shortcut

If I have an environment variable in Windows such as `%username%` if there any way I can [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989009/javascript-substring) that?  I'd like to [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989009/javascript-substring) it down to the first 8 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem. Do it this way:

```
ECHO %username:~0,8%
```

Quoting from 'SET /?': May also specify substrings for an expansion.

```
%PATH:~10,5%
```

would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5
characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the expanded
result.  If the length is not specified, then it defaults to the
remainder of the variable value.  If either number (offset or length) is
negative, then the number used is the length of the environment variable
value added to the offset or length specified.

```
%PATH:~-10%
```

would extract the last 10 characters of the PATH variable.

```
%PATH:~0,-2%
```

would extract all but the last 2 characters of the PATH variable.